# how to add onblur function for columns in EnhancedGrid

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid, dojo.gridx

I have a dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid which have some editable columns, editable columns should not allow space values, when I give space values it should trim the value. By onblur I can trim the value. But in enhanceGrid how to add onblur function for columns.